# Error when running Azure Runbook "Cannot find the 'Test-AzPowerBIEmbeddedCapacity' command"

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm trying to auto-shutdown a PowerBI Embedded Capacity Plan in Azure using a Powershell Run book (code below) but receive the following error:

> *At line:42 char:20  + ... PBEmbExisit=Test-AzPowerBIEmbeddedCapacity -Name $PowerBIEmbeddedName ...  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Cannot find
> the 'Test-AzPowerBIEmbeddedCapacity' command. If this command is
> defined as a workflow, ensure it is defined before the workflow that
> calls it. If it is a command intended to run directly within Windows
> PowerShell (or is not available on this system), place it in an
> InlineScript: 'InlineScript { Test-AzPowerBIEmbeddedCapacity }'*

I have installed the latest Az.Accounts and Az.PowerBIEmbedded modules for the Automation Account and see these listed:

[Screenshot of installed modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrEi5.png)

I've run the 'Update Az Modules' option on the Automation Account too.

Does anyone have any ideas about why this won't run?

Script:

```
workflow powerbi-embedded-wflow 
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]
        $AzureResourceGroup,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]
        $PowerBIEmbeddedName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [Boolean]
        $Suspend
    )
    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"

  try
    {
        # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
        $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName        
 
        "Logging in to Azure..."
        Add-AzureRmAccount `
            -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
    }
    catch {
 
        if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
        {
            $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
            throw $ErrorMessage
        } else{
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            throw $_.Exception
        }
    }

    #checking if the PowerBI Embedded Capacity Exisit
    $IsPBEmbExisit=Test-AzPowerBIEmbeddedCapacity -Name $PowerBIEmbeddedName

    if($IsPBEmbExisit -eq $true)
    {
        if($Suspend -eq $true )
        {
            try
            {
                #Suspending the Service
                "Suspending $PowerBIEmbeddedName started"
                $SuspendOperation = Suspend-AzPowerBIEmbeddedCapacity -Name $PowerBIEmbeddedName -ResourceGroupName $AzureResourceGroup -PassThru
                "$PowerBIEmbeddedName is Suspended Successfully"
            }
            catch
            {
                    Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
                    throw $_.Exception
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                #Resuming the Service
                "Resuming $PowerBIEmbeddedName"
                $ResumeOperation = Resume-AzPowerBIEmbeddedCapacity -Name $PowerBIEmbeddedName -ResourceGroupName $AzureResourceGroup -PassThru
                "$PowerBIEmbeddedName Resumed Successfully "
            }
            catch
            {
                    Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
                    throw $_.Exception
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        "The Provided Resource $PowerBIEmbeddedName doesnot exist"
    }
}
```

Comment: You can refer to [Save on Your PowerBI Embedded Capacity](https://www.drewsk.tech/2019/12/26/save-on-your-powerbi-embedded-capacity/), [How To Use Azure Automation To Resize Power BI Embedded Capacities](https://medium.com/@mrthomasjackson93/how-to-use-azure-automation-to-resize-power-bi-embedded-capacities-1d5b678ad8ea) and [about_InlineScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_inlinescript?view=powershell-5.1&WT.mc_id=ps-gethelp)

Comment: You can ask this question on [Power BI Community Forum](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Get-Help-with-Power-BI/ct-p/PBI_GetHelp)